# Property selection is not supported on values of type 'Integer'

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to send this dynamic content:

```
content:@concat(formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-1),'mm'),formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-1),'dd'))
```

from web activity in Azure Data Factory to logic Apps.

on the logic app side I have defined such a body:
[image]

in the second step I would like to extract the value:
[image]

but after running at this step I get this error:

```
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Extract' inputs at line '1' and column '1292': 'The template language expression 'triggerBody()?['ID']' cannot be evaluated because property 'ID' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'Integer'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ave you tried to define the ID property as an integer ? In your schema it is defined as a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From my test and your error message, your `ID` in your content must be like this:

```
{
    "ID":222223
}
```

In this way, The `ID` would be in `String` type. So you need to change your `ID` into String type like this:

```
{
    "ID":"222223"
}
```

Or change your JSON Schema "ID" type to Integer and the `Variable Type` to Integer. Then the logic apps will work.

[image]

Comment: While this works, this shouldn't be the accepted answer because most of the ids you are working with in a Microsoft ecosystem look like {E2B4BAA6-2132-EA11-A810-000D3AB1160E}, which clearly cannot be parsed as an Integer. Content-Type = application/json is the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Add

```
Content-type = application/json
```

in request header.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer to the question.

Comment: This was the issue for me, thanks a lot! Was stuck on this for hours, they could really improve the error logging.

I kept getting the error: "Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'"